# Find smallest positive number that is a odd number position

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, pascal

I have array number generator program and I need it to search smallest positive number that is a odd number position in Pascal.

Here is my program:

```
Program UZD5_linx;
uses crt, Math;
var MasGen:array [1..20] of real;
    i,id:integer;
    x,sk,MinVP:real;
    MAKE:text;
    funk:string;
    label SAKUMS,DZOB,REZ,BEIGAS;
begin
  assign(MAKE, 'Gnerejums.txt');
  rewrite(MAKE);
  clrscr;
  randomize;
SAKUMS:
    writeln('Darbibas');
    writeln('Ievadisana - Darbs');
    writeln('Uzdevumu beigsana - Beigas');
    writeln('Parbaude - Test');
    read(funk);
    if funk='Darbs' then goto DZOB; //main generetor
    if funk='Beigas' then goto BEIGAS;//end
    if funk='Test' then goto REZ;//The main algorithm
    readln;
DZOB:
  writeln('Ievadiet savu mainigo sin vertibu');//Read in the value
  readln(x);
  {skaitlu generacija}
  for i:=1 to 20 do
  MasGen[i]:=cos(random(20))+(random(10))*sin(x)-tan(random(30))-random(25)-cot(x);
  for i:=1 to 20 do
  begin
  writeln('Nr= ',i,' ','Vertiba=',MasGen[i]:2:3);
  writeln(MAKE,'Nr= ',i,' ','Vertiba=',MasGen[i]:2:3);
  end;
  readln;
  writeln(MAKE);
  goto SAKUMS;
REZ:
    //Algorimhm here
    goto SAKUMS; //Sakums = Start
BEIGAS:
  close (MAKE);
end.
```

I need that after my generated array to test and write out the smallest number that is positive `sk[i]` and then write out its position in its array I that is a odd number position (like `1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,18`). And tell which one contains the smallest positive possible value. But if it hasn't got any then print that it has none of this number.

I hope you really understand what I need this algorithm to do. English isn't my native language. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ["Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem**"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The problem is that after number array generated in this programm it needs to tell me the smallest positive number that is in odd number position. I personaly tried for i:=1 to 20 do cycle test, but it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A repeat until loop starting with i = 1 and adding 2 for every cycle will let you target the odd indexes.

A minIx variable controls whether a positive min value is found and which index it has.

```
i := 1;
minIx := 0;
minVal := 0;
repeat
  if (arr[i] > 0) then begin // Positive value
    if (minIx = 0) or (arr[i] < minVal) then begin
      minVal := arr[i];
      minIx := i;
    end; 
  end;
  i:= i+2;
until i > 19;
if (minIx > 0) then 
  WriteLn('Min:',minVal,' Ix:',minIx)
else
  WriteLn('No positive values in odd index positions.');
```